# PHP Array unique values

Tags: php, arrays, array-unique

I have an array like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => BA
            [name] => British Airways
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => BA
            [name] => British Airways
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => LA
            [name] => Lanchile
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => LA
            [name] => Lanchile
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => BA
            [name] => British Airways
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => BA
            [name] => British Airways
        )

)
```

and i want to get

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => BA
            [name] => British Airways
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => LA
            [name] => Lanchile
        )
)
```

but after using array_unique function, all i have is

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => BA
            [name] => British Airways
        )

)
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try using `array_unique(my_array, SORT_REGULAR)` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/q/307674/608170. Also if this array is the result of a query, you need to recheck your query so as to eliminate the duplicates.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766942/php-unique-array-function-for-nested-array

Comment: Dont know how to mark comment as an answer, but 'diegoperini' you right, array_unique(my_array, SORT_REGULAR) + sort() solved the problem! :)

Comment: Wish I saw these comments 1 hour earlier. I don't think you can mark comments as an answer. You should answer the question yourself, give @diegoperini credit and mark the answer as completed.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
array_unique(my_array, SORT_REGULAR)
```

As requested in comments. :)

Comment: U would rather say - Great "steallution" lol
Upvoted diegoperini in deep concern of justice.

Comment: I misread Niklas Ekman's suggestion that day and now I realize it was stealing. Apologies for the inconvenience. I upvoted the question instead.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned array_unique doesn't support multi dimensional arrays, but you could iterate over the data and build your own

```
<?php
$airlines = array(
    array('id' => 'BA', 'name' => 'British Airways'),
    array('id' => 'LA', 'name' => 'Lanchile'),
    array('id' => 'BA', 'name' => 'British Airways'),
    array('id' => 'LA', 'name' => 'Lanchile'),
    array('id' => 'BA', 'name' => 'British Airways'),
    array('id' => 'LA', 'name' => 'Lanchile'),
);
$tmp = array();
foreach ($airlines as $item) {
    if (!in_array($item['id'], $tmp)) {
        $unique[] = $item;
        $tmp[] = $item['id'];
    }
}

var_dump($unique); // $unqiue will have your desired results in it var_dump was just for testing
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 array_unique is not intended to work on multi dimensional arrays.
```

You need to loop the array

[array_unique](https://www.php.net/array_unique)

Answer (score 1):

```
$airlines = array(
    array('id' => 'BA', 'name' => 'British Airways'),
    array('id' => 'LA', 'name' => 'Lanchile'),
    array('id' => 'BA', 'name' => 'British Airways'),
    array('id' => 'LA', 'name' => 'Lanchile'),
    array('id' => 'BA', 'name' => 'British Airways'),
    array('id' => 'LA', 'name' => 'Lanchile'),
);


$unique = array_map(
    'unserialize',
    array_unique(
        array_map(
            'serialize',
            $airlines
        )
    )
);

var_dump($unique);
```

Comment: That would fail if the order of the elements are different. `array_unique($airlines, SORT_REGULAR);` is the correct answer.